# Vaadin PWA to TWA transformation with bubblewrap

Tags: vaadin, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I am developing a PWA App and want to transform it to a TWA with Bubblewrap, but I get the following error:

```
Building the Android App...
    - Generated Android APK at ./app-release-signed.apk
    - Generated Android App Bundle at ./app-release-bundle.aab

Failed to run the PWA Quality Criteria checks. Skipping.
```

Does anyone know where I have to start to fix it?

Comment: I don't really know what your app is built with, I'm not sure what TWA with bubblewrap is, and there is not really much context on why it is not succeeding. You should really add a lot of context, links, logs, screenshot and other information to be able to attract the correct people that can help you to end up here.

Comment: "Failed to something: skipped" does not really sound like a hard error.

Comment: its true, is working also if this "warning" occurs. strange

Comment: If you know TWA i am really sure, that you would understand. So maybe your answer is not that helpful in those questions.

So thank you @cfrick its only a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the lines before that, the application was generated successfully.

This error just means that Bubblewrap was unable to generate a Lighthouse and check your PWA against the quality criteria.